# Is it possible to save the client certificate from a SOAP Web service?

Tags: java, web-services, ssl, soap, glassfish

I have been trying to implement Authentication and Authorization based on digital certificates using GlassFish as web server and SOAP UI to test the functionality of my application but as part of the Authentication process I need to save the log from all the messages information including the alias found in the cacerts file of glassfish from the client that consumes the web service and the content of the message.

Is it actually possible to do this from the application layer? I have tried with a Message and Logical handler on server side but I can't see anything related to the digital certificate, the only clue I have is that SOAP UI gets the server certificate from client side.

Answer (score 0):

After some research and some fails about this I ended up adding the certificate details to the project on the web descriptor and catching the username from that, after that find the alias of that username and finally searching the alias in the TrustStore to get the public key.

At first on the web.xml file we need to add the details for authentication:

```
<!-- Security constraint for resource only accessible to role -->
<security-constraint>
  <display-name>WebServiceSecurity</display-name>

  <web-resource-collection>
    <web-resource-name>Authorized users only</web-resource-name>
    <url-pattern>/ExampleWSService</url-pattern>
    <http-method>POST</http-method>
  </web-resource-collection>

  <auth-constraint>
    <role-name>user</role-name>
  </auth-constraint>

</security-constraint>  

<!-- BASIC authorization -->
<login-config>
  <auth-method>CLIENT-CERT</auth-method>
</login-config>

<!-- Definition of role -->
<security-role>
  <role-name>user</role-name>
</security-role>
```

And on the sun-web.xml we add the role mapping and the details from the clients, this can be retrieved with the public key.

```
<sun-web-app>
  <security-role-mapping>
    <role-name>user</role-name>
      <!-- <group-name>wsusers</group-name> -->
     <principal-name>CN=Name, OU=Department, O=Organization, L=City, ST=State, C=nl</principal-name>
  </security-role-mapping>
  <security-role-mapping>
    <role-name>user</role-name>
    <group-name>wsusers</group-name>
  </security-role-mapping>
</sun-web-app>
```

Based on this tutorial: http://javaeenotes.blogspot.com/2010/10/securing-jax-ws-web-services.html